# Proof problem is NP

Tags: complexity-theory, np

Hi need help to proof:

For each A,B problems , if A ≤p B , and B ∈ NP then A ∈ NP

Thanks.

Comment: What I tried? I have no idea how to solve it. That is why I am asking for help.

Comment: Maybe you need to try harder. Do you understand the relevant definitions (what is NP? What does $\leq_p$ mean, and so on). That's an important first step.

Comment: where do not get frustrated pal, what is NP? you can verify B in polynomial time right? and what does that make A? I am sure it is all written in the textbook such as CLRS, maybe read it, and when you got stuck you can ask here.

Answer (score 2):

There are two equivalent definitions of $\text{NP}$.

The one is verifier-based:

> $\text{NP}$ is the set of decision problems whose solutions can be *verified* in polynomial time.

The other one is machine-based:

> $\text{NP}$ is the set of decision problems which can be *solved* in polynomial time by some *non-deterministic* (Turing Machine) algorithm.

**Hint:** Try both definitions to see which one is more suitable to your problem.

---

Maybe you can first solve the easier problem to warm up:

> If $A \le_{p} B$ and $B \in P$, then $A \in P$.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a site policy for this, but I would at least personally advise against answering questions that show no effort. If we answer problem dumps, we only encourage behavior that ultimately lowers the site quality.

Comment: The question can be deleted. I will ask in other forums.

Comment: @Juho Yes, I agree with you. So I only give a hint here (and a more question). I will be watchful in the future. Thanks for pointing it out.